# Do not nest generic types in member signatures error by fxcop when used tuple as ienumerable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-structures, parallel-processing

Hi I want to return pair of strings. I am right now using `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` as a return type but fxcop gives warning. I am using concurrentBag with Parallel.For so want to avoid `ConcurrentDictionary<string,IList<string>>` or `ConcurrentDictionary<string,Concurrentbag< string>>`. Also new class or struct does not make sense. What will be the proper solution.

Thanks a lot,
Omkar

Comment: I think you should ignore the warning in this case.  It doesn't make much sense to create a non-generic subclass of Tuple for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah now you will see the question perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel the the type you're using is optimal, you should ignore / suppress the warning.

However, you should probably replace the `Tuple<string, string>` with a custom class that has meaningful property names.

Comment: Really? I just want to send data to other function.. why do I need different class for that?

Comment: You don't _need_ another class.  However, using a new class will make your code far more readable.  Overuse of tuples is a bad sign.